# its posibile to create a custom batch for moving custom extension files to new created folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
move *.docx %userprofile%\Documents\ move *.pdf %userprofile%\Documents\ move *.txt %userprofile%\Documents\ move *.xls %userprofile%\Documents\
```

all this in one cmd ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) is just a series of commands separated by new lines:

```bat
Move *.docx "%UserProfile%\Documents\NewDirectory"
Move *.pdf "%UserProfile%\Documents\NewDirectory"
Move *.txt "%UserProfile%\Documents\NewDirectory"
Move *.xls "%UserProfile%\Documents\NewDirectory"
```

Or concatenators, *(the ampersand `&`)*:

```bat
Move *.docx "%UserProfile%\Documents\NewDirectory" & Move *.pdf "%UserProfile%\Documents\NewDirectory" & Move *.txt "%UserProfile%\Documents\NewDirectory" & Move *.xls "%UserProfile%\Documents\NewDirectory"
```

You could also use a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop):

```bat
For %%I In (docx pdf txt xls) Do Move "*.%%I" "%UserProfile%\Documents\NewDirectory"
```

The biggest problem with all of the above methods is that for most commands Windows sees `*.ext` as any extension beginning with `.ext`, this means, for instance that `.xls` would actually include `.xlsb`, `.xlsm` and `.xlsx` extensions too.

There are a few ways of preventing such issues, the first is to use `if` commands:

```bat
For %%I In (docx pdf txt xls) Do If /I Not "%%~xI"==".xlsb" If /I Not "%%~xI"==".xlsm" If /I Not "%%~xI"==".xlsx" Move "*.%%I" "%UserProfile%\Documents\NewDirectory"
```

By filtering the results with [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr):

```bat
For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%I In ('Dir /B /A:-D *.docx *.pdf *.txt *.xls 2^>NUL ^| "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /V /I "\.xlsb$ \.xlsm$ \.xlsx$"') Do Move "*.%%I" "%UserProfile%\Documents\NewDirectory"
```

The problem with all of the methods above is that they expect the destination directory to actually exist first, which means you'd need to use the `MD` command, i.e. `MD "%UserProfile%\Documents\NewDirectory" 2>NUL`

Using [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy), *(which despite its name can also `move` files)*, the destination directory would also be created automatically, if it didn't already exist and you could use its `/XF` option to exclude those possibly rogue file extensions too:

```bat
"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "." "%UserProfile%\Documents" *.docx *.pdf *.txt *.xls /Mov /XF *.xlsb *.xlsm *.xlsx
```

I have used `"."` to represent the current directory as the source directory, *(you could of course use a specific full or relative path if required)*.